# Unable to retain values of dependent select box in Drupal 7

Tags: ajax, drupal-7

I have two dependent dropdown one for country and one for state. I am using the concept multiple times in a multistep webform.
When the form loads, the list of country is okay. On selecting a particular country the state list is also okay. 
Now comes the issue: 
If there is some mandatory field in the same part of webform, and the user does not fill that up the form refreshes and loses the entire list of states. Also, when moving to the next step (Multi step webform) and coming back to the same page the value is lost. 
However in the entire process the value of country select list is retained. 
The select options generated using ajax are not retained.
Thanks in advance. Below is the code used.

```
$form['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['address_of_employer']['country']['#ajax'] = array(
        'callback' => 'my_custom_ajax_callback_for_employer_one',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-submitted-employment-history-employer-1-address-of-employer-state',
        'method' => 'replace',
        );

    /*
     * Implements Ajax callback for populating list of provinces (Employer One).
    */

     function my_custom_ajax_callback_for_employer_one($from, $form_state)  {
         $selected_country = $form_state['values']['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['address_of_employer']['country'];
         $states = location_get_provinces($selected_country);
         $form['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['address_of_employer']['state']= array(
             '#type' => 'select',
             '#options' => $states,
             '#attributes' => array('id' => 'edit-submitted-employment-history-employer-1-address-of-employer-state'),
             );
         $form['rebuild'] = TRUE;
         return $form['submitted']['employment_history']['employer_1']['address_of_employer']['state'];
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

My initial thought is that you should be passing the form and form state by reference ($from, $form_state) should be (&$form, &$form_state) on your ajax callback (as well you have a typo).